# Probability of losing everything in N games

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Consider a gambler who starts with an initial amount of money of $£i$, obtains $£R$ with probability $p$ and loses $£J$ with probability $q=1-p$. What is the probability that it loses everything if he plays maximum $N$ times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to model the scenario by a Markov chain in which a state represents how much money you have, transitions depending upon $ p,  q,  R $ and $ J $, and then find the probability of being in a state where your money equals $ 0 $ in $ n $ steps.

This can be formulated recursively as follows.

- Let $ a $ be the state in which you have exactly $ \$ 0 $ and let $ S
     $  be the set of all states.
- Consider all states $ b \in S $ such that there is a directed edge
  from $ b $ to $ a $.
- Let $ p(n, a) $ denote the probability of being in state $ a $ in
  exactly $ n $ steps.

$$ p(n, a) = \sum_{b \in S} p(n - 1, b) \cdot \delta(b, a)$$ 
 where $ \delta(b, a) $ is the transition probability from state $ b $ to $ a $.

Comment: Hi. I don't know why I didn't accept this as a correct answer 5 years ago. It's time to fix that.

Comment: Haha, thank you :)